# Statistical test suggestion for algorithm comparison

Tags: statistical-significance, genetic-algorithms

I have 8 different algorithms (based on well-known genetic algorithm). Each algorithm is tested with 50 independent runs for 4 different benchmark problems. Also, each problem has 24 different cases inside them (I don't know if this information is required but I wanted to tell just in case). To sum up:

- Each algorithm has 96 different results for 96 different test environments (4 problems x 3 environments x 2 something else x 4 something else another)
- From 8 x 96, I have 768 different `.csv` files, each has 50 independent runs' answers.

Which test I should use for a statistical significance?